# how to show data in pagination bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I want to implement pagination to show some data using bootstrap. But I don´t know what to put in the href="#" to show the data in that page. Is static data, I don´t want to bring data from a database.

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#listarTabContent1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#listarTabContent2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#listarTabContent3">3</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="listarTabContent1">
        <h1>HOLA 1<h1>
    </div>
    <div id="listarTabContent2">
        <h1>HOLA 2<h1>
    </div>
    <div  id="listarTabContent3">
        <h1>HOLA 3<h1>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Bootstrap's Pagination is decorative only; it is meant to style your pagination output, not provide pagination functionality.  You would have to provide that through some other means.

Comment: i think what you need is a carousel, i recommend you owl carousel 2, it comes with multiple examples